# Unsetting a flag (clearing a bit) in x86, x64 and ARM assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, arm, x86-64

If this is the way you check if a flag is set:

For x86:

```
mov     edi, ds:(dwTestFlags_ptr - 0FEEEEEE0h)[ebx]
test    byte ptr [edi], 80h
```

For x86-64:

```
mov     rbx, cs:dwTestFlags_ptr
test    byte ptr [rbx], 80h
```

For ARM:

```
LDR     R3, =(dwTestFlags_ptr - 0xAAAAA)
LDR     R6, [R4,R3] ; dwTestFlags_ptr ; "033"
LDR     R3, [R6]
TST     R3, #0x80
```

What are the possible ways to unset it for each architecture?

Comment: Define _"unset"_. Do you mean _clear_, as in _set to zero_?

Comment: It could be "clear" as you say. Or maybe "remove" or "delete" as remove a flag held by a variable in C. I'm a newbie in programming, I accepted a challenge from a friend. Thank you

Comment: Well, x86 has `BTR` and ARM has `BIC`. Look them up in the respective instruction set references.